# Постраничная навигация для Gallery

Tags: modx, php

Подскажите как реализовать постраничную навигацию для галереи.
У меня стоит вот такой код

```
[[!Gallery? &album=`1` &limit=`8` &thumbTpl=`galItemThumbPort` &thumbWidth=`215`     &thumbHeight=`154` ]]
```

лимит стоит 8 фотографий на страницу, как сделать что бы можно было переключать по страницам ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется на специализированных форумах по modx вам бы быстрее ответили но вообще http://forums.modx.com/thread/38126/getpage-not-fully-working-with-gallery

Comment: На форуме MODx я уже задал вопрос, но не сказал бы что там быстрей. Здесь до первого ответа или комента проходит минут 10-15 там же пол дня

Comment: в общем постраничка появляется если предать все параметры: total и page передать в getPage, раньше я немного правил компонент Gallery для этого сейчас незнаю должно быть уже. Сейчас попробую найти пример в старых сайтах

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста маленький примерчик

Comment: вот ветка в которой написано, решение: http://community.modx-cms.ru/blog/questions/6454.html

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы Вам не сделать галерею на **jQuery**? Будет и удобно и красиво.

Делается все очень просто:

**CSS:**

```
#gallery {
    padding: 20px;
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    width: 483px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 380px;
}

#big {
    background-image: url("images/gal/loader.gif"); <!-- Картинка load -->
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    width: 483px;
    height: 302px;
    border:1px dotted #cccccc;
    }

#small {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 33px;

}

#small a img{
    border:none;

}
```

**html:**

```
<div id="gallery">
<!-- Стартовая картинка -->
<div id="big"><img src="images/gal/start.jpg" alt="Старт" /></div>
<div id="small">
<!-- Здесь ваши картинки, можно через php циклом вывести -->
<a href="images/gal/1.jpg"><img src="images/gal/1_mini.jpg" alt="Миниатюра 1" /></a>
<a href="images/gal/2.jpg"><img src="images/gal/2_mini.jpg" alt="Миниатюра 2" /></a>
<a href="images/gal/3.jpg"><img src="images/gal/3_mini.jpg" alt="Миниатюра 3" /></a>
<a href="images/gal/4.jpg"><img src="images/gal/4_mini.jpg" alt="Миниатюра 4" /></a>
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#small a').click(function(data){
    $('#big img').hide().attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));
    $('#big img').load(function(){
      $(this).fadeIn(1000);
    });

    data.eventDefault();

  });

});
```

Вот таким образом, можно сделать галерею на **jQuery**.

**Главное:**

*Я использовал два типа картинок: маленькие, те которые оглавляют галерею, и большие, которые, собственно, главные в галереи. Но вы можете использовать только один тип, большие, а потом их просто уменьшить.*

Comment: Дело в том что для меня и так сошло бы, но галерея это как отдельная страница сайта, который на CMS, и этим сайтом управлять буду не я один. Представь когда не знающий человек решит добавить фотку, это будет полный ахтунг))) Мой начальник уже как то раз поменял на сайте текст, так я потом не нашел куска страницы )))))

Comment: @Berserker, Запилить админку для нубов ;)

Comment: Не админку мне не зачем делать, я их уже и так достаточно сделал, хочу изучить CMF MODx, поэтому решение с такой галереей не пойдет, мои нубы должны добавлять удалять инфу безопасно для сайта.

Comment: @Berserker, я понял :)